# The Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation: classical solutions versus weak solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, laplace-transform, calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations

Let $B_R$ a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider $u^{\star} \in H^{1}(B_R) $ and $f \in  H^{1}(B_R) \cap C(\overline{B_R})$. Suppose that $u^{\star}$ minimizes 
$$\int_{B_R} |\nabla u|^2, u \in \{ v \in H^{1}(B_R); v - f \in H^{1}_{0}(B_R)\} .$$

Let $u^{\sharp} \in C^{2}(B_R) \cap C(\overline{B_R})$ such that $\Delta u^{\sharp} = 0 , $ in $B_R$ (pointwise) and $u=f$ in $\partial B_R$ (pointwise). It is reasonable to expect that $u^{\sharp} = u^{\star}$. I am not seeing how to prove this, someone could give me  help?

Comment: You have that $\int_{B_r}\nabla u\nabla \phi=0$ for all $\phi\in H_0^1(B_R)$. From this, you can get enough regularity.

Comment: Hey Tomas, I did a mistake in the hipothesis, the correct is $u^{\star} \in H^1 (B_R) $ and not $u^{\star} \in H^1 (B_R)\cap C(\overline{B_R}) $